# Smartphone with 2 different serial number

Tags: android, smartphone

Because in the android smartphone if you type the code *#06# from the numeric keypad, in addition to the IMEI, the serial number is shown, but then if you go to settings and view the serial number, here it is different from the one displayed via the code *#06# ?

Comment: Can you tell us which phone it is? Just tested on a Galaxy A32 and they are the same

Comment: Xiaomi redmi note 9 pro

Comment: BTW, not every phone will do that with *#06#.  USSD codes vary in support by carrier, OEM, dialer app (the dialer is an app not part of the OS), etc.

Comment: But for this phone the code *#06# is used, which shows both IMEI and serial number, I don't understand you are saying that with this code a wrong result could be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

From what I found, the good serial number is the one in settings. Sometimes the serial number can be found on the case (or inside) starting by "S/N", or if you have it will be on the original box. You can compare to verify this is the good one.

From [this answer at XDA Forums](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/serial-number-in-status-different-from-box-and-phone-sticker.4420775/#post-86626487):

> It's not uncommon for the [USSD] software to be misreporting the serial number sometimes. Xiaomi has some bugs, but as long as it's not breaking, it's fine